# Previous div won't de-highlight on clicking sibling div

Tags: jquery

I am developing a web application where I have eight div elements having same class and which are dynamically generated. I want to highlight a particular div on click and de-highlight it when I click on another div.So far, I have tried following code block, which is not working. I have researched and tries different tweaks but at current stage it highlights in red the divs i click but won't remove highlight from previous one. The code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".imageDiv").on("click", (function(e) {
    //alert("Jquery Hit !!");
    $(".imgDiv").removeClass("imgDiv-selected");
    $(this).addClass("imgDiv-selected");
    //$(this).addClass(".imageDiv-selected").siblings().removeClass(".imageDiv-selected");
    $(".imgDiv-selected").css("border-color","red");


}));
});
```

Please give your valuable insights as this sounds simple but taking me a lot of time.

Edit : The divs are created as follows. There is no HTML as such :

```
images.forEach(function callback() {

    var elem1 = document.createElement("div");
    elem1.setAttribute("class", "imageDiv");
   // elem1.onclick = clicked;
    document.getElementById("images").appendChild(elem1);
    var img1 = document.createElement("img");
    img1.setAttribute("class", "image");
    img1.src =images[cnt++];
   document.getElementById("images").appendChild(elem1);
    elem1.appendChild(img1);


});
```

Regards,

Comment: remove the starting ( from (function(e) and ')' from }));

Comment: Is this line `$(".imgDiv").removeClass("imgDiv-selected");` supposed to be `$(".imageDiv").removeClass("imgDiv-selected");`? From what you are describing, it sounds like you should be removing the class from the same class you are firing the click event on. Could you post the HTML code as well?

Comment: DinoMyte removing the brackets did not help either..

Comment: Hi DHP...please see my edit...

Comment: @Newcoder, did you try changing the selector for removing the class from `$(".imgDiv")` to `$(".imageDiv")`? `imgDiv` doesn't seem to be a valid class from the code you posted.

Comment: @DHP...yes I just did...I think as long as the click is on .imageDiv...does not matter what name is inside...however i did change that but no gain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements are generated dynamically, you need to delegate the events:

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready
$(function() {
    // Delegated .on() syntax
    $(document).on("click", ".imageDiv", (function(e) {
        // If you know you'll only ever have one image selected
        // at any given time, look for the class and then remove
        // it rather than looping through all the images.
        $(".imgDiv-selected").removeClass("imgDiv-selected");
        $(this).addClass("imgDiv-selected");
        $(".imgDiv-selected").css("border-color","red");
    });
});
```

This attaches the event handler to the parent element. When the click event bubbles up and is identified by jQuery as having originated from `.imageDiv`, this handler will fire.

**Note:** Delegating at the `document` level is extremely inefficient. It's best to delegate at the closest containing parent that exists on initial page load.

**Reference:** [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Edit:**

As a test case for changing `$('.imageDiv').removeClass('imgDiv-selected');` to `$('.imgDiv-selected').removeClass('imgDiv-selected');` here is a [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/removeclass-looping-vs-direct) test showing the resulting difference.

Comment: Thanks War10ck...tried the above code but did not work...still cant dehighlight the previous...will look at test cases..

Comment: @War10ck...Thanks...it finally worked...but I had to define style on the .imageDiv-selected in css file....for some reason it was not working if I applied the styles through jquery i.e. $(".imgDiv-selected").css("border-color","red");....selecting this as answer as more efficient solution performance wise...thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind an event, such as `click`, to a dynamically created element like this:

```
$("your selector").on("click",function() {}
```

Then, you would be able to add/remove class to each of these elements when click occurs:

```
$(".divStyle").on("click",function() {
   $(".divStyle").removeClass("divSelected");
   $(this).addClass("divSelected");
});
```

With a little bit coding, you can deselect a selected div when clicked, like this:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("divSelected")) {
  $(".divStyle").removeClass("divSelected");
}
else {
  $(".divStyle").removeClass("divSelected");
$(this).addClass("divSelected");
}
```

Check out this working example on [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/bEMgQP)